# I updated taget version but my App on Store's compatibility still is "Ios 11 or later"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, version, ios14

Like a title, I updated taget version but my App on Store's compatibility still is "Ios 11 or later". How to update compatibility? Thank!

[image]

Comment: Did you change [this](https://imgur.com/ox5mnIY) too?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, I changed deploy, but not work, my App on Store's compatibility still is "Ios 11 or later" :)))